# WPF Animate Window Visibility Change

Tags: wpf, animation, visibility

I'm trying to figure out how to animate the change from Visibile to Hidden for a WPF window. The way I currently have the application working is that the window is normally hidden and when I move the mouse to the side of the screen it pops out, I'm using a boolean to visibility converter to do that but what I would like to do is to have the application slide out more smoothly on mouse over as well as slide back in again afterwards.

I haven't don't anything with animations so I'm not sure how to do this. Firstly I'm not really sure what animation I should use the do this, secondly I'm not really sure whether I should trigger this on the "IsWindowVisibile" property in the viewmodel or if I should bind it to the VisibilityChanged event and thirdly I'm not sure if this is possible when the window size is variable.

**[Edit]**

If necessary I will 'take' an opacity solution but that's not exactly the 'sliding' effect I am trying to get.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I did something like that (opacity goes to 0 during 2 seconds and window hides): just look at code, it's simple

MainWindow.xaml:

```
    <Storyboard x:Key="hideMe">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:2" To="0.0"/>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="showMe">
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:5" To="0.75"/>
    </Storyboard>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
    public void ShowMe() {
        (FindResource("showMe") as Storyboard).Begin(this);
    }
    public void HideMe() {
        (FindResource("hideMe") as Storyboard).Begin(this);
    }
```

Just call `HideMe()` or `ShowMe()` instead of setting `Visibility = Visibility.Hidden` in code

**Edit**

WPF is slow when moving windows, so if you need sliding animation:

1. Make a transparent window (`AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent" WindowStyle="None"`)
2. Put all your controls onto opaque panel (`Background="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"`)
3. Animate this panel's `Margin.Left` from `0` to window's `ActualWidth`, then hide a window - this will remove a problem of saving window size

Comment: This mostly works. My window is already transparent so I'm just binding it directly to the Window.Left property. I'm also doing it in code behind instead of XAML because I need to window width to depend on a view different factors

Comment: I want to use this code for a DockPanel Panel, but I can not put Storyboard in the xmal file, how can i do it ?

Comment: @icaptan You'll need to create a storyboard in code, like `var sb = new Storyboard(); sb.Children.Add(opacityAnimation); sb.Children.Add(visibilityAnimation); sb.Begin(this)`

Comment: but why not in xaml file like your example ? i try it soon ! thanks

Comment: @icaptan In the previous comment you stated that you cannot put it to xaml, so I proposed non-xaml way

Comment: @MykolaBogdiuk, I have tried your code, i set my window opacity to 0, i called window `Show()`, then your code `ShowMe()`. Window is not reaching opacity 1, there is a little transparent. i want it to reach opacity 1.0.

Comment: @PraneshJanarthanan did you change `0.75` to `1.0` in `<DoubleAnimation ...>`?

Comment: @MykolaBogdiuk, No, I am new to WPF. As already said in earlier comment. i Used your code exactly with a additional setting xaml window opacity to 0.

Comment: @PraneshJanarthanan well, my question was the answer then. `<DoubleAnimation ...>` allows you to specify animation properties such as animated property `TargetProperty`, `Duration` and final property value `To`.

Comment: @MykolaBogdiuk, Oh! I didn't notice your double animation line of code under `ShowMe`. So I just copied the same from your `Hideme` and specified the `To=1.0`. but your code `To=0.75` was placed in the second order. So your code was in effect my code was overridden.

Answer (score 3):

Playing with a Window's `Opacity`/`Visibility` requires a simple `DoubleAnimation`.

### Example:

```
IsVisibleChanged += new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(MainWindow_IsVisibleChanged);

void MainWindow_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation()
    {
        From = (IsVisible) ? 0 : 1,
        To = (IsVisible) ? 1 : 0,
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
    };

    BeginAnimation(Window.OpacityProperty, da);
}
```

### Problem:

For this to work as expected, you need to set `AllowsTransparency` to `True` on your window. If you don't set this, your window with `Opacity` set to `0` will be `Black`.

The problem is for this property to be `True`, you need to have `WindowStyle` as `None`. Which means no frame around your window. That means no close, minimize, maximize, restore, title bar.

You have to provide a custom template (probably inherit `Window` class) to put these buttons up there.

Comment: I'm trying to use your solution but while it fades in correctly when IsVisible == true, when IsVisibile == false it disappears straight away instead of the opacity changing and then disappearing

Comment: This is likely happening because we're being set to not visible before the animation is being run.