# Animation not working in Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Well I have two problems both related to animation.

1)  The following code does not animate the tittle and border i am calling the following like this.FadeIn(), this being of type UIElement of course.

```
public static void FadeIn(this UIElement targetControl)
    {
        DoubleAnimation fadeInAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(0, 1, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5)));
        Storyboard.SetTarget(fadeInAnimation, targetControl);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fadeInAnimation, new PropertyPath(UIElement.OpacityProperty));
        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
        sb.Children.Add(fadeInAnimation);
        sb.Begin();
    }
```

2) This is also not working, no animation is shown.

```
public static void SkewAnimation(this UIElement targetControl) 
{ 
   DoubleAnimation skewAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(0, 360, new    Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)));
   Storyboard.SetTarget(skewAnimation, targetControl);

   Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(skewAnimation, new  PropertyPath(SkewTransform.AngleXProperty)); 
   Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
   sb.Children.Add(skewAnimation);
   sb.Begin(); 
}
```

Comment: When you say this.FadeIn(), you mean you are using it as an Extension Method of type UIElement?  Is that correct?

Comment: yes i am using this as an extension method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not simply animate like this:

```
public static void FadeIn(this UIElement element)
{
    element.BeginAnimation(
        UIElement.OpacityProperty,
        new DoubleAnimation(0d, 1d, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5)));
}
```

and, provided that the element's `RenderTransform` property is set to a SkewTransform:

```
public static void SkewAnimation(this UIElement element)
{
    ((SkewTransform)element.RenderTransform).BeginAnimation(
        SkewTransform.AngleXProperty,
        new DoubleAnimation(0d, 360d, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3d)));
}
```

EDIT: This would require something like

```
element.RenderTransform = new SkewTransform();
```

or in XAML:

```
<SomeElement>
    <SomeElement.RenderTransform>
        <SkewTransform />
    </SomeElement.RenderTransform>
</SomeElement>
```

---

Not sure why your FadeIn won't work, but your SkewAnimation can't work due to the property path. `SkewTransform.AngleXProperty` is not defined for UIElement. The property path would have to be something like this (again provided that RenderTransform was set to SkewTransform):

```
new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.(SkewTransform.AngleXProperty)");
```

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Media.MatrixTransform' to type 'System.Windows.Media.SkewTransform'. when i call your skew method and                                                 
 and in my skew function when i changed what you said the following exception occured   Cannot resolve all property references in the property path 'RenderTransform.(SkewTransform.AngleXProperty)'. Verify that applicable objects support the properties.

Comment: Well, you haven't posted the relevant code. I can only guess what you've put into the RenderTransform property, or if it even is RenderTransform. In my example i have assumed that RenderTransform was set to a SkewTransform instance. It's up to you do that.

Comment: thanks ,it works now,but why animation on tittle does not work

Comment: the on which we have close,min,max button and title name

Comment: last solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501754/wpf-animate-window-visilibty-change answered my problem.